# Are all the files of the application deleted when application is updated?

Tags: android

I would like to know if all the files (database, configuration) of the application are deleted when application is updated.  If yes, then how can i save them during the update?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973154/upgrading-android-version-cleans-application-data

Answer (score 1):

The database and user preferences are not deleted. If you need to update the database, override the `onUpgrade` function in your `DatabaseHelper` class.